# How to make predictions on new dataset with tensorflow's gradient tape

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradienttape

While I'm able to understand how to use model.fit(x_train, y_train), I can't figure out how to make predictions on new data using tensorflow's gradient tape. My github repository with runnable code (up to an error) can be found [here](https://github.com/Relative0/Predict_Images_with_Questionnaires). What is currently working is that I get the trained model "network_output", however it appears that with gradient tape, argmax is being used on the model itself, where I'm used to model.fit() taking the test data as an input:

```
network_output = trained_network(input_images,input_number)

preds = np.argmax(network_output, axis=1)
```

Where "input_images" is an ndarray: (20,3,3,1) and "input_number" is an ndarray: (20,5).

Now I'm taking network_output as the trained model and would like to use it to predict similarly typed data of test_images, and test_number respectively.

The error 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'predict' here:

```
predicted_number = network_output.predict(test_images)
```

Which is because I don't know how to use the tape to make predictions. However once the prediction  works I would guess I can compare the resulting "predicted_number" against the "test_number" as would usually be done using the model.fit method.

```
acc = 0

    for i in range(len(test_images)):
        if (predicted_number[i] == test_number[i]):
            acc += 1

    print("Accuracy: ", acc / len(input_images) * 100, "%")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain prediction I usually iterate through batches manually like this:

```
predictions = []
for batch in range(num_batch):
    logits = trained_network(x_test[batch * batch_size: (batch + 1) * batch_size], training=False)
    # first obtain probabilities 
    # (if the last layer of the network has no activation, otherwise skip the softmax here)
    prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    # putting back together predictions for all batches
    predictions.extend(tf.argmax(input=prob, axis=1))
```

If you don't have a lot of data you can skip the loop, this is faster than using `predict` because you directly invoke the `__call__` method of the model:

```
logits = trained_network(x_test, training=False)
prob = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
predictions = tf.argmax(input=prob, axis=1)
```

Finally you could also use `predict`. In this case the batches are handled automatically. It is easier to use when you have lots of data since you don't have to create a loop to interate through batches. The result is a numpy array of predictions. In can be used like this:

```
predictions = trained_network.predict(x_test)  # you can set a batch_size if you want
```

---

What you're doing wrong is this part:

```
network_output = trained_network(input_images,input_number)
predicted_number = network_output.predict(test_images)
```

You have to call `predict` directly on your model `trained_network`.